# How to process Update query in shopping cart table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I'm working with PHP, MySQL to develop my online store. Basically till now I have made everything and now I'm working on the cart update process. Which means users can update the quantity of each product they they had added to the cart.

And this is how cart table looks like:

[print screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG6pB.png)

In order to retrieve products from `cart` table in db, I did this:

```
$cart_id = $_GET['cart_id'];
$get_add = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE cart_id = '$cart_id'";
$run_add = mysqli_query($con,$get_add);
$cart_items = [];
$total_price_to_pay = 0;
while ($row_results = mysqli_fetch_array($run_add)){
    $item = array(
        'table_id' => $row_results['table_id'],
        'cart_id' => $row_results['cart_id'],
        'pro_id' => $row_results['product_id'],
        'pro_title' => $row_results['product_title'],
        'pro_price' => $row_results['product_price'],
        'pro_img' => $row_results['product_image'],
        'pro_supplier' => $row_results['product_supplier'],
        'qty' => $row_results['qty'],
        'cart_ip' => $row_results['cart_ip'],
        'pro_total' => $row_results['qty']*$row_results['product_price'],
    );
    $total_price_to_pay +=  $row_results['qty']*$row_results['product_price'];
    $cart_items[] = $item;
}
```

And for showing results of `cart` table in db, I did this:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
foreach ($cart_items as $cart) {
    $pro_id = $cart['pro_id'];
    echo "
    <input type='hidden' name='pro_id' value='$pro_id'>
    <h4><a href=''>".$cart['pro_title']."</a></h4>
    <p>".$cart['pro_supplier']."</p>
    <select name='quantites'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
        <option value='5'>5</option>
    </select>
}
    <input name='update' type='submit' value='UPDATE'></input>
</form>
```

Now for UPDATING the quantity of each item, I added this as action:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        $proid = $_POST['pro_id'];
        $quantities = $_POST['quantities'];
        $update_qty = "
            UPDATE `cart` SET `qty` = '$quantities' WHERE `product_id` = '$proid'
        ";
        $run_qty = mysqli_query($con,$update_qty) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        if($run_qty){
            echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='0; URL=cart.php?cart_id=$cart_id'>";
        }else{
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            die(mysqli_error($con));
        }
    }
?>
```

But now the problem is it does not update the table at all!

No error and no result...

So how can I add this update button inside of this table to be working. Therefore user can change the quantity of each product.

Please if you know how to solve this problem, please let me know.. Thanks!

Comment: Add updated_at=now() in your update query.
UPDATE `cart` SET `qty` = '$quantities', updated_at=now() WHERE `product_id` = '$proid'

Answer (score 0):

update your html form with following code and try now

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
<?php foreach ($cart_items as $cart) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='pro_id' value='".$cart['pro_id']."'>
    <h4><a href=''>".$cart['pro_title']."</a></h4>
    <p>".$cart['pro_supplier']."</p>
    <select name='quantites'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
        <option value='5'>5</option>
    </select>";
} ?>
    <input name='update' type='submit' value='UPDATE'></input>
</form>
```